# Does providing username once cause `ssh` to suddenly not asking for password anymore?

Tags: ssh, permissions, sshd, key-authentication, ssh-agent

For a long time, I was baffled by why ssh command was asking for a password sometimes, and sometimes not.  Even when I was using the **same** private/public key pair on many different clusters, I was sometimes getting asked for a password, and sometimes I was not.

Today I tried accessing a cluster that normally requires a password when I try to ssh into it.  Normally, to access the cluster I do `ssh <ip address>`.  Today, I did `ssh <username>@<ip address>` to get in, and it did not ask me for a password!

And, it hasn't asked me for a password since then.  This is strange...why does just providing the username cause it to not prompt me for a password anymore?  or is there something else that I'm missing that might have changed this?

I checked the permissions on the `~/.ssh` directory and everything looks correct there....what other things to check?

Comment: Could you share your `.ssh/config` or relevant portions thereof? If you're using `ControlMaster` and `ControlPersist`, then the first connection will establish a control socket that later connections may use without authenticating (see the `ssh_config` manual).

Comment: sure, @Kusalananda one second.  I can tell you for sure that I do not have `ControlMaster` and I do not have `ControlPersist`.  So, whatever the default values are for those are what I'm using.  I DO however have `ForwardingAgent Yes`, which might be making a difference here, as was pointed about by some people previously.

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify your question and/or respond to requests for more information; instead,  [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have a password on the ssh *private key*, and that ssh-agent are running somewhere.

When the first connection is made, and there is nothing in the ssh-agent, then it'll ask you the decryption password for the private key. Once it is entered, it'll add it to the ssh-agent, and that'll then (on subsequent connections until it gets cleared) use the key from the ssh-agent.

Comment: I do not have enough points to vote right now, but thank you.

Comment: So @Hvisage you suspect that the client's ssh agent probably did not have this private key attached, and therefore when I first was prompted for the password, it somehow permanently associated my private key with that password, and thus I did not have to enter a password ever since.  Is that what you're saying?   I could understand that being true if I was only asked for a password once, but that is not the case - I was asked for a password every time I ssh'd for the past week.  It was only yesterday that I stopped needing a password.  Do you have any clue why that might be happening? Thanks.

Comment: My only other hypothesis is if the ssh-agent was somehow not running, unbeknownst to me, and at some point it got started yesterday.  and, after it got started, every time after that I did not need my ssh password.  Do you agree with that?

Comment: one way to test your hypothesis, would be to disable the `ssh-agent` on the client side, and then `ssh` into the server.  Then, I could see if it keeps prompting me for a password again and again.  Then I could enable the `ssh-agent`, add the private key to it via `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` and see if it only prompts me for the password once, and then does NOT prompt me any time after that?

Comment: Sounds about right :)